# Basic String Array in c

Tags: c, arrays

```
char p[10]="Hello world";
printf("%u %u",&p,p);
```

Output:

```
4294959568 4294959568
```

Why both are giving the same value? `&p` should give the address of where it is storing the array address right?

What happens when an array is defined? What value will be there in `p` and the array is accessed?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552663/function-pointers-and-address-of-a-function).

Comment: Not an answer but you can use `%p` for pointers `printf("%p %p",&p,p);`

Comment: As char array represents the string so 'p' is the pointer to the string while '&p[0]' is the addres of the first char of the array.

Comment: euhhh, any link to the duplicate?