# In C, when using the name of the function in pthread_create is it the same as using a reference?

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-key-create

I'm not sure if I said it right.

```
   pthread_create(..., ..., &some, ...);
   ...is the same as:
   pthread_create(..., ..., some, ...);
```

I'm learning threads, if you could give a website or a video that makes it really simple, it would be great. Threads - locks, condition variables, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Use the book: Unix SYstems programming by Steven Robbins

Comment: could you please assign a green check mark? we like to recieve them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both function name `some` or pointer to function `&some` to get the address of the function.

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552663/function-pointers-and-address-of-a-function).

Answer (score 2):

Yes because *function name is pointing to a memory location*. In simple words it is a memory address, so you pass it like `foo` or `&foo`, both are the same.

Example Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(){

    printf("hello world");

}

int (*fuu)();

int main (void)
{
   fuu = foo;
   fuu();

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps