# Segmentation fault: 11 when returning stuct via function pointer in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to emulate a constructor. I'm attempting to do this by having a parent Struct have a function pointer that returns a pointer to a child struct. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct child_t {

  char *name;

} Child;

typedef struct parent_t {

  Child (*NewChild)();

} Parent;

Child *NewChild() {
  Child *child = malloc(sizeof(Child));

  child->name = "foo";

  return child;
}

int 
main()
{
  Parent parent;

  Child child = parent.NewChild();
}
```

Comment: What do you think is called with `parent.NewChild()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct child_t {

  char *name;

} Child;

typedef struct parent_t {

    Child * ( *NewChild )( void );

} Parent;

Child * NewChild( void ) 
{
    Child *child = malloc( sizeof( Child ) );

    child->name = "foo";

    return child;
}

int main( void )
{
    Parent parent = { NewChild };

    Child *child = parent.NewChild();

    puts( child->name );

    free( child );
}
```

The program output is

```
foo
```

That is you should declare the function correctly. Its return type must be a pointer. So you must to declare the function pointer correctly in the structure definition

```
typedef struct parent_t {

  Child (*NewChild)();
  ^^^^^^
} Parent;
```

And you need to initialize the object of type Parent.

```
Parent parent = { NewChild };
```

otherwise it has an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like you haven't initialized `parent.NewChild`. Try setting that to the function pointer before calling it, like this: `parent.NewChild = NewChild;`.

Also, aren't you missing the `*` in `Child *child = parent.NewChild();`?

Addendum: By the comments, there is also an error/conflict in the declaration of `Parent`:
Its `NewChild` member function is declared to return a `Child`, while the free method `NewChild` returns a `Child*`. So declare the member function pointer as `Child * (*NewChild)();`.

Comment: And I would point the fact that `child->name = "foo";` is probably not doing what is actually intended.

Comment: BTW, the `&` is not needed.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, removed it. Is it just not needed or actually wrong?(Haven't done any real C programming for a while, only C++)...

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552663/function-pointers-and-address-of-a-function). Or in the nutshell, it's the same

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work. I'm getting incompatible types: `incompatible pointer types assigning to 'Child (*)()' from 'Child *(*)()' parent.NewChild = &NewChild;` & 'initializing 'Child *' (aka 'struct child_t *') with an expression of incompatible type 'Child' (aka 'struct child_t')
  Child *child = parent.NewChild();`

Comment: I think it should be `Child* (*NewChild)();` in the `parent` type definition.

Comment: `Child *NewChild()` returns `Child *` but `Child (*NewChild)()` is defined as a function pointer to a function returning `Child`.  It should be `Child *(*NewChild)()`

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

I see the following problems in your code.

**Mismatching function and function pointer**

In `Parent`, you have defined `NewChild` as:

```
Child (*NewChild)();
```

That says `NewChild` is a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Child` object.

The function that you have defined:

```
Child *NewChild() { ...
```

Takes no arguments and returns a pointer to a `Child`, not an object of `Child`.

You'll have to decide which one needs to be fixed. To fix the function, make its return type `Child`.

```
Child NewChild() { ...
```

**Uninitialized `Child` of `parent`**

You have left the value of `parent.Child` uninitialized yet you are trying to use it.

**Setting the member of `Child`**

You use the following code to set the `name` of `child`.

```
child->name = "foo";
```

This may or may not be a problem depending on how you use `child->name` since `child->name` points to some global data in the computers read-only memory. It will be better to make a copy of `"foo"`.

Here's my suggestion for updating your code:

```
Child NewChild() 
{
   Child child;

   // strdup is available on some platforms but it can 
   // be implemented easily.
   child->name = strdup("foo");

   return child;
}

int main()
{
   Parent parent;
   parent.NewChild = NewChild;

   Child child = parent.NewChild();
}
```