# Overloaded pointer to function

Tags: c++

I was looking over the following code:

```
string toUpper(string s) {
    string result;
    int (*toupperp)(int) = &toupper; // toupper is overloaded
    transform(begin(s), end(s), back_inserter(result), toupperp);
    return result;
}
```

I am confused by this line:

```
int (*toupperp)(int) = &toupper; // toupper is overloaded
```

1.Why is this line necessary?

2.I believe that `&` retrieves a pointer to something from memory. But `toupper`, the name of the function is already a pointer, no? Why can't we do this:

```
int (*toupperp)(int) = toupper;
```

3.Why is the function overloaded to `int` if it's used on a `string`?

Comment: 3. It is not used on `string`, but on every `char` of the `string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) It's not necessary, really. If you have used `using namespace std` directive, it's necessary to cast to the desired type to [let the compiler know which overload you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942442/2436175). So, you might also say

```
transform(begin(s), end(s), back_inserter(result), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(&toupper));
```

Otherwise the following should be enough:

```
transform(begin(s), end(s), back_inserter(result), ::toupper);
```

2) Identifiers that are function names decay into pointers, yes, but they aren't exactly the same thing. That being said, in this case it should be fine to say

```
int (*toupperp)(int) = toupper;
```

or even (if you haven't used `using namespace std` directive):

```
auto toupperp = toupper;
```

3) it's for compatibility with C standard library. It's used on every element of `s`, which for `string` is a `char`.

Comment: I think [`toupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) has no overload, does it?

Comment: @Antonio good point for clarification. `::toupper` is not overloaded, but `std::toupper` is - look up in [`<locale>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/toupper)

Comment: There's also a [very interesting comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-do-i-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function/2942442#comment7190884_2942442) on why using the intermediate variable is preferable, I learnt something today

Comment: @Antonio that comment is not right for `static_cast`. Both are the same conversions and both are compile-time errors if there's no such overload.

Answer (score 4):

What you are passing to [`transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is a pointer to the function `toupper` (see [function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)). You store this pointer into the local variable `toupperp`. The type of `toupperp` is a pointer to a function taking an `int` as argument and returning an `int`.

Unless `toupper` is defined in strange ways, the function is seemingly used by `transform` to change each input character to uppercase. Each single character is processed as an integer (with an implicit cast if needed).

Regarding your question 2, using the operator `&` you make more explicit you are taking the address of the function, but indeed you could omit it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552691/2436175) (I learnt something today).

If `toupper` was overloaded, using the intermediate variable is a safe way to get exactly the desired overload. If the desired overload goes away this method will catch the problem at compile time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942442/2436175). (And that's something else I learnt today).