# Verify function pointer equality with Cmockery

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmockery

I am writing Unit test and wondering how would I test function pointers with Cmockery.

A.c

```c
void (*FunctionPtr)(void) = &funcA;

void funcA()
{
  // calls func B 
  funcB();
}
```

TestA.c

```c
void Test_A( void ** state )
{
   // test for FunA; working as expected
}

void Test_FunctionPtr( void** state )
{
  // how to check here that FunctionPtr holds memory location of funcA?
  // I tried something like below:
  assert_memory_equal( FunctionPtr, funcA(), sizeof( funcA() ) );
}
```

During runtime I am getting error and I have no clue how to resolve that. May be I using wrong API to assert but don't know which one to call.

Below is my error:

```
error during runtime:      
Test_FunctionPtr: Starting test
No entries for symbol funcB.
```

Comment: "how to check here that FunctionPtr holds memory location of funcA" --> Have you tried `assert(FunctionPtr == funcA);`?  Note: best practice to _define_ `funcA()` before using it in `void (*FunctionPtr)(void) = &funcA;`

Comment: `funcA()` calls the function `funcA`, which returns nothing which cannot be compared.

Comment: @mch Looks almost like an answer. Would you like to make it one? Maybe add a solution, which I think would be using `funcA` instead of `funcA()`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think chux has the solution. You want to compare the values of the function pointers, not what it points at.

Comment: After reading comments here ,  I modified TestA.c  to have extern funcA and funcD example extern void funcA() ; extern void funcD(). IN test module I have added assert_int_equal( FunctionPtr , funcA ) and it compiled and test passed. For curiousity I gave  assert_int_equal( FunctionPtr, funcD ) and it failed . So i reckon its working

Comment: True, sorry @chux. Would you like to make an answer? Chm, I think your phrasing was more "attractive". :-)

Comment: @mch, Your comment was key to this post.  Recommend that you post an answer or let OP post a self answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`funcA()` calls the function. You want a pointer to the function, which is `funcA` or `&funcA` (does not make a difference which one you use: [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552691/3684343)).

Also you want to compare the value saved in `FunctionPtr` with the address of `funcA`. You do not want to compare the memory where `FunctionPtr` points to with the function.

So instead of `assert_memory_equal( FunctionPtr, funcA(), sizeof( funcA() ) );` I would use `assert(FunctionPtr == funcA);`

You wrote in your comment that you are using `assert_int_equal` now. Note that both values are not `int`, so if the macro uses `printf` with `%d` (or similar) in an error case you are invoking undefined behaviour.