# pthread_create should I use & or not? (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am learning about pthreads but I got one question where I got different answers depending on whom I ask. For example:

```
void *server (void * arg){
   printf("I am running");
   return NULL;
}

int main(int){
   pthread_t thread_server;

   pthread_create(&thread_server, NULL, &server, NULL);

   pthread_join(thread_server, NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

is this correct or should I do it like this?:

```
void *server (void * arg){
    printf("I am running");
    return NULL;
 }

 int main(int){
     pthread_t thread_server;

     pthread_create(&thread_server, NULL, server, NULL);

     pthread_join(thread_server, NULL);
     return 0;
  }
```

Notice the difference at pthread_create (&server, or server). Both seem to work but then what is the difference?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552663/function-pointers-and-address-of-a-function

Comment: As long as there are not two consecutive unary `&` address operators, then it makes no difference what sequence of zero or more unary `&` address and unary `*` indirection operators you apply to the function name, the result will always be a pointer to the function. The rules in C11 6.3.2.1p4, 6.5.3.2p3 and 6.5.3.2p4 ensure it.

Comment: regarding: `void *server (void * arg){`  This will cause a compiler warning due to the unused parameter,  To correct that warning, the first line in the body of the function should be: `(void)arg;`

Comment: in function: `server()` regarding; `return NULL;`  since this is a thread function, a much clearer return statement would be: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Comment: regarding the statement: `int main(int){`  This is not a valid signature for main()`!   Suggest using one of the two valid signatures: `int main( void )` -or- `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: regarding the statement: `pthread_t thread_server;`  a much better variable name would be: `pthread_t threadID;`

Comment: regarding: `printf("I am running");`  This will output the text to the `stdout` buffer.  To get that text to be immediately output to the terminal, end the format literal with '\n'.  I.E.  `printf("I am running\n");`

Comment: regarding the calls to `pthread_create()` and `pthread_join()`  They return an indication of 'success' ==0 or 'failure' != 0.  The code should always check the returned value from C library functions to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "my error msg" );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice the difference at pthread_create (&server, or server). Both seem to work but then what is the difference?

`pthread_create` takes a pointer to a function. Function name implicitly converts to a function pointer, you don't need to take its address explicitly. In other words, both `server` and `&server` do the same thing here - pass function `server` pointer to `pthread_create`.

```
int main() {
    void f(); // Function.
    void(*p)(); // Function pointer.

    p = &f;
    p = f; // Same effect as above.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I do &server, then arent I passing the address of the pointer then and not the address to the thread?

Comment: `server` is a function, not a pointer, so `&server` is the address of the function.

Comment: Now I understand, I was confused about that first * but it makes sense now thx

Comment: @J.Doe You may find [right-left rule](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/rt_lt.rule.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Notice the difference at pthread_create (&server, or server). Both seem to work but then what is the difference?

There is no effective difference.  They are equivalent.

The reference for this (in C11) is [**6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**, paragraph 4 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p4):

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the`_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning type" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning type".

Given the function

```
void *server (void * arg){
   printf("I am running");
   return NULL;
}
```

The bare `server` identifier in `pthread_create(&thread_server, NULL, server, NULL);` is such a "function designator", so it is implicitly converted to a function pointer.  `&server` already has the type "pointer to function".