# How to declare a function pointer?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I came across these two programs:

```
int* getb(int* p);
void main()
{
    int x = 5 ;
    int* ptr = getb(&x);
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
}

int* getb(int* p)
{
    int* re = (int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    *re = *p *= 2;
    return re;
}
```

```
void fun(int a) 
{ 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 
} 

int main() 
{ 

    void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun; 

    (*fun_ptr)(10); 

    return 0; 
}
```

What is the difference between the function pointer declarations in the two programs?

```
int* getb(int* p);
```

and

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun;
```

Comment: @Dai, why provide type information if the memory location used stores no information about type - just for the space needed?

Comment: @AdrianM. What "type information" are you referring to?

Comment: @Dai, the variable type, such as 'int'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int* getb(int* p);
```

This is not a function pointer, it's a [function prototype](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/c13.htm). C compilers don't "look ahead" for functions, so if you're calling a function that hasn't been defined yet you need to put a prototype that lists the function's parameters and return type above the call site. That's what's happening in the first program.

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun;
```

This *is* a function pointer. It creates a variable named `fun_ptr` that points to the function `fun()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* getb(int* p)
```

This is not a function-pointer declaration. It's a **forward declaration** of the `getb` function.

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun;
```

This **is** a function-pointer variable declaration.

Note that in C, the address-of operator `&` is implicit, so these two statements behave the same:

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun; 

void (*fun_ptr)(int) = fun;
```

See here: [Function pointers and address of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552663/function-pointers-and-address-of-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
int* getb(int* p);
```

is not a declaration of a function pointer. It is a declaration of a function that has the return type pointer to int that is `int *` and one parameter of the same type: pointer to int.

The function type is

```
int * ( int * )
```

To declare a pointer to the function type you have to write for example

```
int * ( *fun_ptr )( int * ) = getb;
```

This declaration

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = &fun;
```

is indeed a declaration of a pointer to function type `void( int )` that is initialized by the address of the function `fun`.

You could write

```
void (*fun_ptr)(int) = fun;
```

because function designators used in expressions are converted to pointers to the functions.

And to call the function used as an initiliazer of the pointer `fun_ptr` you could just write

```
fun_ptr(10);
```