# C - Why are myfunc and &myfunc both function pointers?

Tags: c, function, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do all these crazy function pointer definitions all work? What is really going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi)

Is there any special reason? In most cases, &mypointer should give the address of the pointer itself, right?

Comment: Why both `arr` and `&arr` are pointers when `arr` is a static array?