# Passing function by reference or by value?

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool myfn(int i, int j) { return i<j; }



int main () {
int myints[] = {3,7,2,5,6,4,9};

 // using function myfn as comp:
cout << "The smallest element is " << *min_element(myints,myints+7,myfn) << endl;
cout << "The largest element is " << *max_element(myints,myints+7,myfn) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

considering the above code , is there any difference if we pass`myfn` or `&myfn` to     `min_element`? when we tried to pass a functor which one would be a more standard way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically, pass-by-reference and pass-by-value only refer to passing variables, not functions. (Template functions introduce some complications, but that is for another discussion.) Here you are passing `myfn` as a pointer to a function. There is no difference if you use `&myfn` instead. The compiler will implicitly convert `myfn` to a pointer to the function with that name.

Comment: That's not entirely true. You can have a function template deduce a function *reference* type as well as a pointer type...

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not all that familiar with that part of template programming. I have updated my answer to take that into account. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: OK, if you have `void f();` and `template <typename R, typename ...Args> bar(R(&func)(Args...));`, then when you call `bar(f)`, `func` will be deduced as a function *reference*. However, *saying* a function reference immediately makes it decay to a function pointer...

Comment: @KerrekSB As I stated in my edit, the complications from templates aren't germane to this particular question and should be post-poned for another discussion if they become an issue.

Answer (score 6):

> is there any difference if we pass myfn or &myfn to min_element?

No. `myfn` gets implicitly converted into *pointer-to-function*, anyway. So there is no difference at all.