# GL_POLYGON working strangely

Tags: opengl, graphics

On the right is the shape generated by GL_LINE_STRIP and on the left is it generated by GL_POLYGON.

[image]
There's a function which generates each point 1 by 1 in order.

Why is there such a big difference in the basic shape? Notice how less 'curved' each portion of the cloud is in the GL_POLYGON version.

Any clue how to fix this? Or maybe use something else to fill this polygon I have?

Comment: fairly impressive it drew the way it did, it's still concave somehow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GL_POLYGON`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml#description) is only for [convex polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons#Convex_polygons):

> `GL_POLYGON`: Draws a single, ***convex*** polygon.  Vertices `1` through `N` define this polygon.

You'll have to [triangulate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12604642/44729) your polygon and use `GL_TRIANGLES` instead.

Or [abuse the stencil buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285096/44729).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could "shade" the fragments inside of the polygon. Just like a [polygon filling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)