# Result of unary & operator applied to a function

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers, c99, unary-operator

C99 6.3.2.1/4

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except
>   when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or **the unary &
>   operator**, a function designator with type "function returning type"
>   is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function
>   returning type".

As I understand, this suggests that except when `sizeof` operator and unary `&` operator is applied to function; no function to pointer conversion will happen. But from what I've seen,

```
int (*p)(int) = &foo;
```

or,

```
int (*p)(int) = foo;
```

Both seems to work. This shows that both `&foo` and `foo` are equivalent. So, where does unary `&` operator comes in affect if it has effect as seen above?

Comment: The short answer is:  functions are weird.  See ["Why do all these crazy function pointer definitions all work? What is really going on?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi)  (While that question asks about C++, I don't know of any substantial differences.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You somehow understood it backwards. On the contrary, *function* type automatically decays to *function pointer* type *unless* the function identifier is used under `sizeof` or `&`.

Again, under `sizeof` and `&` function type *does not* decay to pointer. In all other cases it decays to pointer type. (This, in turn, leads to the fact that applying `sizeof` to functions is illegal.)

The behavior of function types in C mirrors the well-known behavior of array types: unless you use them under `sizeof` or `&`, they are immediately and implicitly converted to pointer types.

This means in your examples expressions `&foo` and `foo` are equivalent. In the first case the pointer is produced by the explicit application of `&`. In the second case, the pointer is produced by the implicit "function type decay" feature. The pointer value is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
int (*p)(int) = foo;
```

the automatic conversion to a function pointer takes place, so that it is equivalent to

```
int (*p)(int) = &foo;
```

where the conversion to a function pointer is not automatic but achieved by the `&` operator.

The implicit pointer to which `foo` is usually converted has no address that could be taken. And if its address were possible to be taken, it would not be the address of `foo`.