# Passing function pointers as arguments

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I was revisiting function pointers in C using the following simple code:

```
unsigned TestFn(unsigned arg)
{   
    return arg+7;
}

unsigned Caller(unsigned (*FuncPtr)(unsigned), unsigned arg)
{
    return (*FuncPtr)(arg);
}
```

I called it using

```
Caller(TestFn, 7)  //and
Caller(&TestFn, 7)
```

both gave the same output : 14. What's the explanation of this. I had been using the second way of calling earlier.

Comment: I believe address is implicitely passed when you pass TestFn, so it is interpreted actually same like &TestFn.

Comment: I think this question answers it, even though it's C++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions work kind of like arrays here. Suppose you have:

```
char hello[5];
```

You can refer to the address of this variable directly as `hello` - the variable name "decays" into a pointer - or as `&hello`, which explicitly obtains the address.

Functions are the same: if you write `TestFn` it decays into a function pointer. But you can also use `&TestFn`. The latter form might be better because it is familiar to more people.

Comment: Thnx, as you said in case of arrays where hello and &hello are same, I experimented with the func ptrs and saw that they are a step ahead with: &ptr, ptr, *ptr, **ptr, ****..*ptr all being same. This appears a bit different from the arrays where dereferencing will give the element value.

Comment: Yes, it is a little different: when you dereference a function pointer you obtain a function, represented by its address. But the address is also the value of the pointer. So if p is a function pointer, p == *p == **p == ...

Answer (score 2):

Just like you pass the address of string without using the ampersand `'&'` sign, you don't need to use the ampersand sign to say you are passing a `function pointer` . You can search the book by K & R  . It contains a good explaination