# Why does setting function pointer as pointer and pointerpointer work?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

One more time I got trapped by pointer logic.
The following code uses a function typedef tOutFunction.
It defines a global variable to this function pointer and a set method.

Why does

```
SetOutFunction(OutFunction);
```

and

```
SetOutFunction(&OutFunction);
```

both work? How could autoconversion work in this place. Or is one of it wrong and it works by accident?

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*tOutFunction)(const char*);

int OutFunction(const char* out)
{
  std::cout << "OutFunction:" << out << "\n";
  return 10;
}

tOutFunction out__ = 0;

void SetOutFunction(tOutFunction outFunc)
{
  out__ = outFunc;
}

int main()
{
  SetOutFunction(OutFunction);
  std::cout << out__("Without Ref") << "\n";

  SetOutFunction(&OutFunction);
  std::cout << out__("With Ref") << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Also tried it here:
http://codepad.org/yfxj2QAo

Comment: RandyGaul- How did you find it. I swear I searched for it for some minutes.

Comment: Googled "address of function c", was the first search result : ]

Comment: for more thought provocation, why does `SetOutFunction(*****OutFunction);` work?

Comment: newacct - You won't get me again because I read http://stackoverflow.com/a/6893288/101635