# print the memory location of a variable (or pointer)

Tags: c, variables, pointers, memory-address

I want to print where a variable is stored. I Google it and I found this:

```
int *p;
printf("memory location of ptr: %p\n",  (void *)p);
```

If I write this, is it right?

```
printf("memory location of ptr: %p\n",  &p);
```

I compiled it and I didn't get any errors or warnings. However, the above two commands didn’t return the same value!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets say you have these declarations:

```
int i;
int *p = &i;
```

It would look something like this in memory:

```
+---+     +---+
| p | --> | i |
+---+     +---+
```

If you then use `&p` you get a pointer to `p`, so you have this:

```
+----+     +---+     +---+
| &p | --> | p | --> | i |
+----+     +---+     +---+
```

So the value of `p` is the address of `i`, and the value of `&p` is the address of `p`. That's why you get different values.

Comment: Lets summurise: the `(void *)p` prints the memory location of the object that the pointer shows and the &p shows the memory location of the pointer itself.right?

Comment: ok then a follow question! Since the value of p is the memory address of the object he shows.. Couldn't i just print the value of p? sth like that `printf("%s", p);` (i run it but i had an warning of format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ so isn't right i guess...

Comment: @Nat95 Since `p` points to an `int`, you of course have to print an integer (to begin with), and to get the value that `p` points to you have to use the dereference operator `*`, so do `printf("%d\n", *p);`

Answer (score 4):

> if I write this, is it right?

No. This is not right. For `%p` specifier you must have to cast it to `void *`. Your compiler should give [warning](http://ideone.com/1UYBO0) about this:

```
warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Werror=format=]
```

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17506236/2455888). It says that:

*The `%p` format requires an argument of type `void*`. If pointers of type `int*` and `int(*)[10]` have the same representation as `void*` and are passed as arguments in the same way, as is the case for most implementations, it's likely to work, but it's not guaranteed. You should explicitly convert the pointers to `void*`*

### Draft n1570; 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:

> p  The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>   manner.

---

> but theses two statements don’t return the same value if I put both of them in the program.

Yes,it will not return the same value. `P` will give you the value of address of the variable `p` points to (pointee) while `&p` will give you the value of the address of pointer `p` itself. Cast `&p` to `void *`.

```
printf("memory location of ptr: %p\n",  (void *)&p);
```

Comment: Ok, but why I don't get any warnings? (I use ubuntu via VirtualBox)

Comment: In C, all pointers can be implicitly casted to `void *`, as well as the opposite.

Comment: Enable your `Wextra` flag in your compiler settings .

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; Could you elaborate it more.

Comment: For example, `free` takes a `void *` argument, but you don't have to cast it. As well as `malloc` returns a `void *` but you don't have to cast that either. In fact, you *should* not cast `void *` arguments and returns, as that might hide subtle bugs when the functions are not properly declared. That is, this how it is in C, in C++ you have to cast.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; Then why I am getting warning in case of `%p` specifier, specially ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "&" operator on a pointer, you create a pointer to the pointer. So the result in your case would be an int**.

**printf** expects a void* when you use the %p specifier, therefore the first way is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, the two don't do the same thing.

The first will print the value stored in `p`. You would usually expect this to be the address of an `int` (though people do the darnedest things).

The second will print the address of `p`. However, you need to add a cast to `void *` for portability reasons, so the second should read

```
printf("memory location of ptr: %p\n", (void *)&p);
```

> I want to print where a variable is stored.

So the answer to your question depends on which variable you are concerned with? For the `int` that `p` points to you want to use the first one. For the variable `p` itself you want to use the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int *x = &i;

    i = 8;
    printf("value of i is %d\n",i);
    printf("value of x is %d\n", *x);
    printf("address of x is %p\n",x);
    printf("address of i is %p\n",&i);
}
```

output:

~/workspace/C$ ./test

value of i is 8

value of x is 8

address of x is 0x7fff793b09c4

address of i is 0x7fff793b09c4