# how to print address of a variable in C?

Tags: c

I try to print the value of address and it generates an error.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60};
    int *ip;
    ip=&arr[3];
    printf("%u",ip);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this has anything to do with Ubuntu... Consider retagging your post to get the proper audience.

Comment: @lenz stack.c:9:1: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%d",ip);

Comment: I don't see how anyone can answer or comment on this question without explaining that the value of a pointer **is the address** for the object it points to. That seems to be the breakdown in understanding in this case. `%p` is simply the format specifier that allows you to see it.

Answer (score 6):

As noted the *value of pointer* is the *address of the object* to which it points. You print it using:

```
printf("%p",(void*) ip);
```

If you are interested in the *value of the object* the pointer points to - you need to dereference it, and then use in this case `%d` format specifier:

```
printf("%d",*ip);
```

Comment: @jpw:that was typo. I guess cast is needed because %p expects pointer of type void.

Comment: @jpw: yes %p format requires an argument of type void*. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286451/how-to-print-variable-addresses-in-c & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374880/print-the-memory-location-of-a-variable-or-pointer.