# How to read declarations in c

Tags: c, pointers

So I am new to C just came from Java and I wanted to understand how to read declarations. 
I know I gave one example but I want to be able to read all declarations and understand it clearly. I'm not really asking you guys to solve it but just guide me

```
For example:
            int point *[];
            int point *()[];
```

Comment: Check this out: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: We are not here to be your teachers. You can get this from pretty much ANY book on C. I'd recommend starting with the very first one: [K&R C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%26R_C#K.26R_C)

Comment: If you are "new to C", don't tag C++ unless you specifically are asking about similarities or differences. While it might not make a difference here, the languages and their idiomatic solutions to problems can be very different.

Comment: I don't think either of your examples are valid C declarations. `int *point[];` would be fine, but `int point *[];` doesn't make sense. `*` needs to modify a type -- `foo *` means "pointer to an object of type 'foo'" -- but `point` here is a variable name, not a type.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635774/whats-the-difference-between-the-types-int-and-int-100-in-c/20647498#20647498

Answer (score 1):

For deciphering C declarations use the **Right - Left Rule**

For your example `int point *[];`
is read as **point is array of pointer to int**.

First understand what the symbols mean.

```
* // "pointer to"
[] // "array of"
() // "a function returning"
```

Now that you know the symbols you can decipher any declaration.

For example
 int *(*pointer())();`

**Step 1 Find the Identifier**

```
int *(*pointer())();
       ^^^^^^^
```

In this case it is pointer, so you read as **"pointer is"**

**Step 2 Use Right-Left Rule**

```
int *(*pointer())();
             ^^
```

You move right first, and you'll hit a `()`, so you read as **pointer is function returning**

**Step 3 Continue the rule**

```
    int *(*pointer())();
          ^
```

Then you move right again, but here you have a closing parenthesis `)`,
so you move left of the identifier and here you have a `*`, so you read as **pointer is function returning pointer to**

**Step 4 Continue the rule**

```
int *(*pointer())();
                 ^^
```

Then you keep moving left, but there is a opening parenthesis `(`, so you can't move left, so now you move right. Now you reached the `()`, you read as **pointer is function returning pointer to function returning**

**Step 5 Continue the rule**

```
int *(*pointer())();
    ^
```

Now you can't move right because there are no more symbols, so move left and reach `*`,
you read as **pointer is function returning pointer to function returning pointer to**

**Step 6 Continue the rule**

```
int *(*pointer())();
^^^
```

Now you can't move left or right because you're out of symbols so you read `int`,
you finally have
**pointer is function returning pointer to function returning pointer to int**

Comment: `int point *[];` is invalid AFAIK. An array of pointers would be `int *point[];`.