# Why this assignment is correct while it looks like assigning an int to int*?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

The second assignment gives an error (a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *"), why isn't the same error showing up for the first assignment?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* x = new int[100];
    x[5] = 3;

    int* y[100];
    y[5] = 3;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int* y[100];` is an **array** of pointers to `int`.  `x` **is** a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` ([reason](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)) and don't `using namespace std;` ([reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is of type `pointer to int` and `y` is of type `array of 100 pointers to int`.

Then, `x[0]` is of type `int&` (reference to `int`) and `y[0]` is of type `int*&` (reference to pointer to `int`).

Thus `x[0] = 5` is assigning `int` value to `int` reference (perfectly valid), but `y[0] = 5` is trying to assign `int` value to *a pointer*, which is not valid.

Comment: The type of an indexed array is the underlying type, not a reference to the underlying type.  There are no reference types here.  The expression `x[0] = 5;` assigns an `int` *rvalue* to an `int` *lvalue*.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb how would you explain `x[0] = 5;` then?

Comment: @StephenM.Webb dereferencing a pointer, or indexing an array, gives you a reference to the element at that position.  If it didn't you couldn't assign to it.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb Hmm. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator) is not really clear on the returned type of this operator and I don't have standard to consult, but I don't see how it could possibly work without reference types.

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer or indexing an array gives you an *lvalue* not a reference type.

Comment: Don't forget folks, this is C code (despite the "C++" tag). C does not have reference types so any explanation that requires their existence is incorrect.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb The Q is tagged as C++ so it is C++ code, even if it would compile in a C compiler.  References do exist in C++ and so that is what you get.  We go by the language tag on the question, not what the code looks like.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb Also, how is it C code.  The code has `new` in it and that is **not** C code.

Comment: I believe what Stephen meant is that "array subscripts can also compile as C code, and C doesn't have references", which is a valid point. In C there must be some magic applied instead of nice type,and presumably most compilers implement it the same way in C++, if the standard doesn't clearly state that it must return a reference type.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I could replace the new expression with a malloc call (a remove the useless include directive and using statement) and I'd have pure C code that would compile identically with either a C or a C++ compiler. Going by ISO/IEC 14882:2014 (the C++14 standard) 5.2.1/1(1) [expr.sub] "the result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise" and 5.3.1/1 [expr.unary.op] "the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points".  No ambiguity, no reference types.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb *lvalue referring* means reference.

Comment: I think this issue deserves a separate question (if one does not already exist). The discussion seems too long for comments?

Comment: For further reference, ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (the C11 standard) 6.5.3.2 /4 regarding the indirection operator `*`: "If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has type ‘‘type’’."

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica reference types are defined in ISO/IEC 14882:2014 3.9.2/1.4 [basic.compund] and lvalues are defined in 3.10/1.1 [basic.lval] -- they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

`x` is a pointer to an `int`.  When you `x[5] = 3;` you actually get `*(x + 5) = 3;`, which advances the pointer and then dereferences it to get to the `int` it points to.

With `y` you have the same thing, but `y` isn't a pointer to an `int`, it is a array of pointers to `int`.  That means `*(y + 5)` gives you an `int*&` since the element type of the array is `int*`.  You can't assign an `int` to an `int*`, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration doesn't do what you think it does. This line:

```
int* y[100];
```

does not create an array of `int`s, but of `int*`s.

If you want an array of `int`s, just don't use the `*`:

```
int y[100];
```

This will create an array of 100 `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Andrew Henle, `int* y[100];` is an array of pointers to int but `x` is a pointer to `int`.

A helpful technique to parse any C declaration is to use the so called [Clockwise/Spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635774/whats-the-difference-between-the-types-int-and-int-100-in-c) are also helpful.