# Passing a 2d array as a pointer C

Tags: c, pointers

So I have a recursive function that requires it to be of type void, without turning to global variables how can I pass a 2d array as a pointer and dereference once I edit values in the recursive function? I already tried int * m[10][10], I can't show all of the code since it is an assignment, pointers aren't required in the assignment but global variables are not permitted

```
Void h(int * m[10][10]){
    int x = 5;
    int y = 5;
    *m[x][y]=7;
}
```

That's the general idea

Comment: `int **` is equivalent to int[][], you may have to change the signature to something like `void h(int **array2d, int rows, int columns)`

Comment: @ichramm: `int **` is not equivalent to `int [][]`. The latter is not valid C syntax, but, if necessary dimensions are supplied, it is either a pointer to an array of `int` (in a function parameter) or an array of array of `int` (otherwise). Neither of these is a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Would you dereference the same way.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right, I was just trying to make a point, hope the later method signature clarifies better. It's been a long time since the last time I wrote pure C code http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html

Comment: @ichramm: The latter signature has the same problem. If a two-dimensional array is defined with `int m[10][10]`, it cannot be passed to a parameter declared as `int **array2d`, even if the numbers of rows and columns are also passed. There is no conversion from “array of array of `int`” to “pointer to pointer to `int`”. The latter requires that an array of pointers exist, and no such objects exist just for an array of array of `int`.

Comment: See I am trying to recurse through neighbours of m so I don't know if any of these would work

Comment: @user1995241: What is a neighbor of m?

Comment: By neighbour I worded it wrong but I mean m[x+1][y] m[x-1][y] and etc

Comment: @user1995241: So you do not want to pass the array `m` every time, you want to pass a pointer into some particular position in `m`? That is a different question from passing an array.

Comment: I meant pass an 2d pointer array and dereferencd when you need to edit it, this is getting more complicated than I had hoped

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this

```
Void h(int  m[][10]) {
    ...

    m[x][y]=7;
}
```

Call your function either as

```
h(&m[0]);   // Passing the address of first row of 2D array m.
```

or

```
h(m);       // As array names decays to pointer to first element of the array. Note that 
            // m will decays to pointer to m[0], not m[0][0].
```

Comment: `h(&m[0])` is unnecessary; `h(m)` suffices.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; Yes. But if he wants to pass the address of any row then he could do that easily.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you declared the array supposed to be passed to your function.

If you declared it like this

```
int my_array[10][10];     // array declaration
```

then

```
void fun (int m[10][10]); // prototype of a function accepting my_array
fun (my_array);           // calling the function
```

is what you are looking for.

In that case, `m` is a ***constant*** pointer to 100 contiguous `int`s that are accessed as a 10x10 2D array.

Other possible variant:

```
int * my_array[10];
for (i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) my_array[i] = malloc (10*sizeof(int));

void fun (int m[10][]); // these syntaxes are equivalent
void fun (int * m[10]);
```

or this one:

```
int ** my_array;
my_array = malloc (10 * sizeof (int*));
for (i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) my_array[i] = malloc (10*sizeof(int));

void fun (int m[][]); // these syntaxes are equivalent
void fun (int * m[]);
void fun (int **  m);
```

or this pathological one:

```
int (* my_array)[10];
int a0[10];
int a1[10];
/* ... */
int a9[10];
my_array = malloc (10 * sizeof (int *));
my_array[0] = a0;
my_array[1] = a1;
/* ... */
my_array[9] = a9;

void fun (int m[][10]); // these syntaxes are equivalent
void fun (int (* m)[10]);
```

If your variable declaration and function prototype are not consistent, you will not access the array properly from within your function, read incoherent values, and mess up your memory and possibly crash if you attempt to modify an element.

If you have nothing better to do, you can read [this little essay of mine on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899515/trouble-understanding-what-elements-are-passed-when-passing-multidimensional-arr/20918811#20918811) for further details.

Answer (score -1):

```
void h(int** m) {
    int x = 5;
    int y = 7;
    m[x][y] = 7;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int** a = (int **)malloc(10*sizeof(int *));

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        a[i] = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    }

    h(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A parameter declared as `int **m` cannot accept either a pointer to a two-dimensional array (an array of array) or the usual automatic conversion of an array, a pointer to its first element.

Comment: This is wrong. The array-to-pointer decayment rule is not recursive; `int m[10][10]` decays into `int (*)[10]`.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code in the answer?