# c++ char to int from user input

Tags: c++, string, int

I'm reading in user input for 2 coordinates it goes as follow:

Enter a coord: 10 5

I want to be able to read in the 10 as the row, and the 5 as the column.

Here's what I have.

```
  char coord[5];

  ...

  cout << "Enter a coord: ";
  cin.getline(coord,sizeof(coord));
  row = atoi(coord[0]);
```

So the code is giving me an error on atoi() and if a user enter a number like 10 char can't really read it from the indexes, how would you guys do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could actually use `int`s to represent your coordinates variables and read them like this:

```
int row;
int column;
std::cout << "Enter a coord: ";
std::cin >> row >> column;
std::cout << "Coords: " << row << " " << column << std::endl;
```

As of your error: you get an error on [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) because it gets a `const char *str` as parameter, and as you are using a char array, you'd need to pass it like `int row = atoi(coord); // which will read only the first value`, as arrays are [implicity converted a pointer to the first array element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17506236/1670308) (often said "decays" to a pointer,  because you then lose the ability to call `sizeof()` on the item) when passed to functions this way.