# Are the variables stored on Heap or Stack in C programming language?

Tags: c, heap-memory, stack-memory

Assume you have the code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a=10;
    char b[10]="HELLO";
    const int x=10;
    return 0;
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong:

"a" will be stored in the stack only (not in data segment at all) with its value(10)

"b" will be stored as a pointer (because I think the array is a pointer to the first element) in the  stack and "HELLO" will be stored in heap (like if we are using malloc).

"x" can be stored in data, stack, or text depending on compiler.

Comment: No, arrays are not pointers.

Comment: depends on compiler, optimizing one will not store anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What and where are the stack and heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: @juanchopanza the array variable is a pointer to the first element

Comment: @MosabShaheen No it's not. An array is an array. A pointer is a pointer. An array may 'decay' into a pointer to the first element in certain cases (e.g. when passing it to a function). For proof try printing out `sizeof(b)` and `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: @MosabShaheen No, arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @Kevin if you print "a" or "&a[0]" both are same and they are the address of the first element.

Comment: @MosabShaheen Did you read my full comment? You can't pass arrays to a function (like `printf`) by value. They decay to a pointer to the first element. Run this instead: `printf("sizeof(b)=%zu sizeof(&b[0])=%zu\n", sizeof(b), sizeof(&b[0]));` sizeof is an operator and the result is determined at compile time (no decaying happens).

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

Comment: @Kevin bro array is holding the address of the first element after executing I got: 009CF9B8 009CF9B8 (same address) sizeof(b)=10 sizeof(&b[0])=4 (different size).The difference is because the sizeof function recognises this is as an array so it returns the number of elements instead of 4 which is the pointer size which is the actual size value of the array. but I think in different implementation of sizeof you can return 4 (like toString in java) so it is not changing the nature of the array which is a pointer.

Comment: @KeineLust array is a fixed pointer (not modifiable) to the first element of the array and char * b is a dynamic pointer, but both are pointers.

Comment: @MosabShaheen the address of the array isn't stored anywhere, just like how the address of the `a` in your code isn't stored anywhere. `b` is an array. `sizeof(b)` returns the number of bytes `b` takes up, which also happens to be the number of elements because it's an array of `char`. Replace it with `int b[10]` and you should get 40 (assuming `sizeof(int)==4`). Please google around for array decaying to understand better.

Comment: @kevin brother I didn't mean the address of the array, I meant the address that the array points to i.e. printf("%p %p\n", b, &b[0]); same value. And again sizeof is detecting b as an array (fixed pointer, not decaying, but a pointer) that's why it is showing the number of bytes instead of the real nature of it as a pointer. As a proof try to decay the array through passing it to a function then it will print same size!  f(b); void f(int *b){
 printf("%p %p\n", b, &b[0]);
 printf("sizeof(b)=%i sizeof(&b[0])=%i\n", sizeof(b), sizeof(&b[0]));
}

Comment: sizeof is "detecting" b as an array because b is an array and not a pointer. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c for example to help explain the difference between an array and a pointer. You are just wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Try and assign a *pointer to array N of T* to a *pointer to pointer to T* with warnings enabled and see it fail. An array is not a pointer. See http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3 for specifics on the array to pointer conversion.

Comment: @Kevin  I agree b is a fixed pointer, it is not only pointer (see in compiler also, it is not modifiable)that is why sizeof is dealing with it different because it is fixed with the type, the size, and the value (address) but if you print the value it is same, that means this is an issue in the sizeof function (if you know toString in Java it is much same you can override to give something else). Also when you decay the array, it returns to its nature as a pointer.

Comment: @MosabShaheen I'm just going to end with AN ARRAY IS NOT A POINTER.

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function, it is an operator, and has nothing to do with overriding methods in Java. If you'd read the links provided to you, for example a link to the C11 standard draft, you'd understand why your prints (that lack the required `(void *)` casts) produce the results you observe; when you pass the array as an argument, it is there and then converted to a pointer to 1st element.

Comment: @MosabShaheen . Literally just google "Is an array a pointer", but okay. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html for example. It's pretty old but still relevant. And it's in book form too: http://c-faq.com/book/. Good enough?

Answer (score 1):

> "a" will be stored in the stack only (data segment not possible) with its value(10)

**Correct.**

> "b" will be stored as a pointer (because the array is a pointer to the first element) in the stack and "HELLO" will be stored in heap ( like if we are using malloc).

**Incorrect.**

Think of that line as:

```
char b[10];
strcpy(b, "HELLO");
```

`b` is an array, not a pointer. Stack memory is used for the array.

> "x" can be stored in data, stack, or text depending on compiler.

**Correct.**

Comment: bro array is a fixed pointer (not modifiable) to the first element of the array and char * b is a dynamic pointer, but both are pointers.

Comment: @MosabShaheen, are you asking or are you telling?

Comment: @MosabShaheen, In many expressions an array decays to a pointer but an array is not the same as a pointer. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Comment: @MosabShaheen, see the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506138/when-is-an-array-name-or-a-function-name-converted-into-a-pointer-in-c. You have to trust that if the answer were wrong, it would be downvoted like crazy instead of begin upvoted.