# What is "myfunc" vs "myfunc()"

Tags: c++

A noob question that probbaly applies to C as well as C++. Let's say I have

```
void myfunc() {
    blah;
}
```

So, I call this function with:

```
myfunc();
```

However, no compiler error is produced when I "call" it with:

```
myfunc;
```

Program runs, but myfunc doesn't get called. So, what is C++ interpreting this as?

Now, I'm doing this in the Arduino IDE, all one big lump of code, so I don't get segfaults, etc. So maybe this would throw a runtime error on a dynamically linked host.

Answer (score 3):

`myfunc` without the parens is the address of the function in memory.

For example, if you have to pass a function to some other function, you would do it with that.

A good example of this is in `bsearch` in the c standard library, where you need to pass a user defined comparator function in order to do a generic search.

Comment: `myfunc` without parentheses is not a pointer to the function.  It is the function.  See [Why do all these crazy function pointer definitions all work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi/6893288#6893288) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler just evaluates the expression. Since you're evaluating the name of a function, it's basically a no-op.

It's just like this:

```
int main() {
    42; // evaluates 42 but does nothing with it
}
```

Your compiler should warn you that the result of the expression is unused, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In C `myfunc` or any other function name represents the *function itself*, which will be implicitly converted to a [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer)

> ## Function to pointer
>
> An lvalue of function type T can be implicitly converted to a prvalue pointer to that function. This does not apply to non-static member functions because lvalues that refer to non-static member functions do not exist.
>
> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer

and [`()` is an operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator) that when applies to a function pointer or a function object will invoke that function

> ## Built-in function call operator
>
> The function call expressions have the form
>
> ```
> E ( A1, A2, A3,... )
> ```
>
> where
>
> - E is an expression that names a function
> - A1, A2, A3,... is a possibly empty list of arbitrary expressions, except the comma operator is not allowed at the top level to avoid ambiguity.
>
> The expression that names the function can be
>
> 1. lvalue expression that refers to a function
> 2. pointer to function
> 3. explicit class member access expression that selects a member function
> 4. implicit class member access expression, e.g. member function name used within another member function.

So without the function-call operator `myfunc;` is just a no-op expression that contains a function pointer. If you've turned on compiler warnings (which you should really do) then they'd [shout at you about the issue](https://godbolt.org/z/gg_o9A). GCC says that

> ```
> statement is a reference, not call, to function 'func' [-Waddress]
> warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
> ```

while Clang outputs `warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]`

Comment: It does not become a function pointer.  `myfunc` names the function itself.