# C++ Function Pointer -- why does this work?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

This is a somewhat standard Linked List exercise. I have a function which takes another function and loops through the list, specifically `_node_loop`. Why does the syntax I use work? I haven't seen function pointer syntax that looks like it.

Complete code included for convenience of testing, but my question is specifically about the functions `_node_loop`, `_del_node`, and `_print_node`.

```
#include<stddef.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Node {
public:
    T value;
    Node<T>* next;
    Node(T value_, Node<T>* next_) : value(value_), next(next_) {}
    Node(T value_) : value(value_), next(NULL) {}
};



using namespace std;

template <class T>
class List {
public:
    List() : head(NULL) {}

    void prepend(T val) {
        Node<T>* node_ptr = new Node<T>(val, head);
        head = node_ptr;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "[";
        _node_loop(_print_node);
        cout << "]" << endl;
    }

    ~List() {
        _node_loop(_del_node);
    }

    static List<T> from_array(T tarray[], int N) {
        List<T> ls = List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            ls.prepend(tarray[i]);
        }
        return ls;
    }

private:
    Node<T>* head;

    void _node_loop(void kernel(Node<T>*)) {
        Node<T>* node_ptr = head;
        Node<T>* tmp;
        while (node_ptr != NULL) {
            tmp = node_ptr;
            node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
            kernel(tmp);
        }
    }

    static void _print_node(Node<T>* node_ptr) {
        if (node_ptr->next == NULL) {
            cout << node_ptr->value;
        }
        else {
            cout << node_ptr->value << ", ";
        }
    }

    static void _del_node(Node<T>* node_ptr) {
        delete node_ptr;
    }
};



int main() {
    int my_array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    List<int> my_list = List<int>::from_array(my_array, 5);
    my_list.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid double underscore names, are implementation reserved.

Comment: Whats the problem with that syntax?

Comment: Everything example of function pointers I've seen is like `void funfun(void (*fun)(Node<T>*))`. But if I do that, I get a compilation error. For comparison, what I have here is `void funfun(void fun(Node<T>*))`. Did I miss something?

Comment: Would it be better if I worded it -- "why DOESN'T this work" for the types of examples I usually see? IE, why doesn't `void _node_loop(void (*kernel)(Node<T>*))` work?

Comment: It's called *decaying* (of function parameter types) [dcl.fct]/5 *"After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” or “function returning `T`” is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to function returning `T`,” respectively"*

Comment: @DyP, thanks for your comment. But `kernel` is a function returning `void`, not returning `T`. Or does the compiler not differentiate, as it's a template class?

Comment: @YikeLu I should have quoted more from the Standard ;) the `T` in the quote is referring to a declaration of the form `T D` (both unrelated to your example, but the name `T` happens to occur in the Standard and your code). In your case, `void kernel(Node<T>*)`, the `T` matches `void`, and the `D` matches `kernel(Node<T>*)`. So the *function returning `T`* here is a *function returning `void`*. (The `T` in the quote is a metasyntactic variable.)

Comment: @DyP Ok, then back to the difference, which is: when to use `void (*kernel)(...)` versus `void kernel(...)`. The latter is what I see in all the function pointer tutorials, eg http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/18060/. Is this a matter of `declarators` vs `declarations`? IE, the `void kernel(...)` form would not be legal in a function declaration outside of the class declaration?

Comment: `void _node_loop(void (*kernel)(Node<T>*))` does work. http://ideone.com/0c0kPo

Comment: @rici, thanks, I verified it works too. Which is frustrating, because that's now twice where I've posted a problem and then been unable to reproduce it. I must have had some other syntax error. At least I know why the first case does work when I didn't expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand a bit on a comment I made.

#### What's happening here?

Function parameter types are adjusted (or decayed) directly after parsing the function declaration:

- *array of `some_type`* is adjusted to *pointer to `some_type`*
- *function returning `some_type`* is adjusted to *pointer to function returning `some_type`*
- top-level *cv-qualifiers* are removed (e.g. `int const` -> `int`)

See [dcl.fct]/5; the parameters of the function type are preserved, i.e. the *pointer to function* contains the same parameters as the original function type.

This adjustment is happening *only* in function parameter types. It mirrors some implicit conversions that can be applied to expressions:

- an (lvalue of) *array of `some_type`* can be converted to a *pointer to `some_type`*, pointing to the first element of the array ("array-to-pointer conversion", [conv.array])
- a (lvalue of) *function returning `some_type`* can be converted to a *pointer to function returning `some_type`* ("function-to-pointer conversion", [conv.func])
- qualification conversions, e.g. from `int` to `const int` [conv.qual]

---

#### About function types

A function type is different from a function pointer type, but both are related similar to array and pointer. For example, you can declare (but not define) functions using a function type:

```
typedef void my_function_type(int, double);

my_function_type f0;  // declare the function `void f0(int, double)`
my_function_type f1;  // declare the function `void f1(int, double)`

int main()
{
    f0(42, 1.2);
    f1(42, 1.2);
}

#include <iostream>
void f0(int, double) { std::cout << "f0\n"; }

// illegal:
//my_function_type f1 { std::cout << "f1\n"; }

void f1(int, double) { std::cout << "f1\n"; }
```

You can have references and pointers to functions, using a function type:

```
my_function_type& my_ref = f0;
my_function_type* my_ptr = f1;
```

In the last line, the function-to-pointer conversion is used. It's equivalent to:

```
my_function_type* my_ptr = &f1;
```

Calling a function pointer *does not* require using a unary `*`. This is syntactic sugar, as it's unambiguous what's meant with, e.g.

```
my_ptr(42, 3.14);
```

Therefore, all of the following are valid:

```
my_ptr(42, 3.14);
(*my_ptr)(42, 3.14);
my_ref(42, 3.14);
f0(42, 3.14);
```

N.B. `()` (function call) has a higher precedence than unary `*`, so the parentheses around `*my_ptr` are required.

As the unary `*` requires a pointer type, you can add as many `*` as you want, see [Why do all these crazy function pointer definitions all work? What is really going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6893285/420683)

---

#### Applying to the OP's example

```
void _node_loop(void kernel(Node<T>*));
```

This member function named `_node_loop` returns `void` and takes a parameter of type `void(Node<T>*)`. This parameter type is adjusted to `void (*) (Node<T>*)`, so the declaration of `_node_loop` is equivalent to:

```
void _node_loop(void (*kernel)(Node<T>*));
```

Inside this function, the parameter `kernel` is used:

```
kernel(tmp);
```

We can call a function through a function pointer without using `*`. But we could be more explicit (I wouldn't recommend it):

```
(*kernel)(tmp);
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you for expanding! One question -- are function references allowed as parameters? ie void G(void (fun&)(...)).

Comment: @YikeLu Yes, but the syntax is analogous to function pointers: `void G(void (&fun)(...))`.

Comment: Any reason why func refs as parameters are not in tutorials? The ref version seems more idiomatic C++ (versus idiomatic C).

Comment: @YikeLu Function pointers are often used for C (or C-compatible) interfaces, and C doesn't have references. Also, in C++, you can pass arbitrary "callable" things to a function template (like, e.g., [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)); there's also `std::function` and `std::bind`, so you typically don't (have to) deal with function pointers/references directly. Also, function references are much less useful than references to objects (you can only call a function reference, and the syntax is the same as for function pointers).