# c assign function pointer to variable

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I have two functions,

```
//virDomain is some struct
int virDomainCreate(virDomain*);
int virDomainDestroy(virDomain*);
```

How do I assign these two functions to a variable?

I tried,

```
int (*func)(virDomain*) = NULL;
func = virDomainCreate(virDomain*); // not working
func = &virDomainDestroy(virDomain*); //not working
```

Thanks for all your help!
Waka.

Comment: also, try `func = &virDomainDestroy;`

Comment: This post might help clarify how to use function pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: You might find http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html useful, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just assign the pointer to the function like:

```
func = &virDomainCreate;
```

Or you can just use the short format:

```
func = virDomainCreate;
```

Comment: I would add that maybe func = &virDomainCreate is the safe way to do it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi

Answer (score 1):

The return type is int so

```
int func;
func = virDomainCreate(virDomain*); 
func = virDomainDestroy(virDomain*);
```

will work.