# Is the asterisk optional when calling a function pointer?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, language-lawyer

I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere. I just read K&R and saw them calling a function pointer like this:

```
(*ptr)(arg1, arg2);
```

I vividly remember, however, to have seen someone using them like this:

```
ptr(arg1, arg2);
```

That might have been in C++, though.

- How are the rules?
- Do they differ in C and C++?

Comment: Did you try that with a decent (and recent) compiler?

Comment: Both work in my clang, but I'm still not sure if that's how it's supposed to be.

Comment: The rules in C and C++ are the same for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-function-pointer-definitions-work-with-any-number-of-ampersands-or-as

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<sup>**TL;DR**</sup>

<sup>The rules in C and C++ are the same, there's no difference between the two.</sup>

---

**What does the C++ Standard ([n3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) say?**

> `5.2.2p1` **Function call** `[expr.call]`
>
> > A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses
> >     containing a possible empty, comma-separated list of
> >     initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function.
> >
> > **The postfix expression shall have function type or pointer to function type**.

---

**What does the C standard ([n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) say?**

> `6.3.2.1p4` **Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
>
> > A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, **a function designator with type "function returning *type*" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning *type*"**.

> `6.5.2.2p1` **Function calls**
>
> > **The expression that denotes the called function shall have type pointer to function** returning `void` or returning a complete object type other than an array type.

---

---

**Conclusion?**

How the rule are expressed differs between C++ and C. In C the implicit *function-to-pointer* conversion always applies when calling a function, whereas C++ states that the *"postfix expression"* could be either a pointer, or a variable of function type.

However; your question is if the two ways of calling a function through a pointer differs between C++ and C, and the answer is: **No, there's no difference between `(1)`, `(2)`, and `(3)`**, nor is there a difference between the two languages.

```
(*fptr)(123);   // (1)
```

```
fptr(123);      // (2)
```

```
(***fptr)(123); // (3)
```

---

<sup>**Note**: Be aware that the there's no difference between `(*fptr) (...)` and `fptr (...)` when it comes to calling a function, but that they can be vastly different in other contexts.</sup>

Comment: In this case, is (*fptr) counted as having a function type, just like the name of a regular function is?

Comment: @user3692301 in C++, yes. In C `(*fptr)(...)` is the same as `fptr(...)` because the Standard mandates that the *function designator* is converted to a *function pointer*.

Comment: There's also no difference between (1), (2), and (3): `(*****fptr)(123); // (3)` ;)

Comment: @newacct added to the post, it's a funny example showing the implicit *function to pointer* conversion at play. :)

Comment: Just received a **-1**, may I ask the voter to justify this vote?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp; No. You can't! They just downvote because they want to downvote! (I named them: Ghost Souls).

Answer (score 4):

> How are the rules? Do they differ in C and C++?

No. Dereferencing the function pointer in this context was **never** necessary, as it is redundant.

However, you might still want to use the asterisk-notation to underline that you are calling a function through a function pointer. That may also be the reason for the author of the snippet in your post.

Comment: Interesting that K&R do it then. Does anyone have any idea why?
@LightnessRacesinOrbit: What kind of benefit do you get from knowing the intent in this context?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, but the question is clearly not about the intent. Edited the post though.

Comment: @Arcoth This question may not be, but programming is.

Comment: What other intent could there be?

Comment: Maybe it was necessary in early versions of the language (e.g. early 1970s I mean) and they never changed their style.  K&R2 still casts malloc despite this being a mistake ever since `void *` was added.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't understand how my answer is actually saying the opposite, anyway. Clearly it is redundant, because both a function and a function pointer are function objects (acc. to standard). So what intent is there to clarify, really? That it is a function pointer you are using? Not convincing.

Comment: @AndrewMedico A reader may not see that the thing being called is a variable. The `*` operator makes an indirect-branch call look different from a regular call, even if it's strictly also allowed for direct calls too.