# What does the "int j = (strlen) (str)" means?

Tags: c, string

I found the following code from [bstrlib](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/), in `bstrlib.c` (e.g. line 193) :

```
bstring bfromcstr (const char * str) {
    bstring b;
    int i;
    size_t j;

    if (str == NULL) return NULL;
    j = (strlen) (str);
    i = snapUpSize ((int) (j + (2 - (j != 0))));
    if (i <= (int) j) return NULL;

    b = (bstring) bstr__alloc (sizeof (struct tagbstring));
    if (NULL == b) return NULL;
    b->slen = (int) j;
    if (NULL == (b->data = (unsigned char *) bstr__alloc (b->mlen = i))) {
        bstr__free (b);
        return NULL;
    }

    bstr__memcpy (b->data, str, j+1);
    return b;
}
```

What does the line `(strlen) (str)` mean? This kind of code using `strlen` is quite common in the `bstrlib.c`.

I did some test code on a OSX machine, but I can't either understand nor explain what it means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`j = (strlen) (str);` is essentially the same as `j = strlen(str);`.

Writing the code the way they did will ensure that the *real* `strlen` function (from `<string.h>`) will be used, even if it is *hidden* by a  [function-like macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html#Function-like-Macros) named `strlen()`.

> A function-like macro is only expanded if its name appears with a pair of parentheses after it. If you write just the name, it is left alone. This can be useful when you have a function and a macro of the same name, and you wish to use the function sometimes.

Because in `(strlen) (str)`, `strlen` isn't followed by a pair of parenthesis, the macro won't be expanded.

This example should demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * Only check something like this in if you're
 * planning on changing jobs very soon!
 */
#define strlen(s)   666

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "Stack Overflow";
    size_t j;

    /* This always uses the *real* strlen */
    j = (strlen) (str);
    fprintf(stderr, "(strlen) (str) = %zu\n", j);

    /* This might be using a function-like macro */
    j = strlen(str);
    fprintf(stderr, "strlen(str) = %zu\n", j);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./a.out 
(strlen) (str) = 14
strlen(str) = 666
```

Of course, the following would have worked as well:

```
#include ...
...

#ifdef strlen
#undef strlen
#endif
```

Comment: Is this gnu specific or is it in the standard (and then: which standard)?

Comment: As haccks shows below, this is standard C. The function name is used as a function pointer and then immediately called.

Comment: @jonathan-reinhart, I mean whether this function-like macro behavior is standard C or gnu specific. I mean preprocessor, not compiler (function pointers).

Comment: I'm not aware of any compiler that doesn't support it.

Answer (score 4):

Functions can be used as pointer to itself just like arrays when used in expression. Therefore `strlen(str)` is equivalent to `(strlen)(str)`, `(*strlen)(str)` and `(******strlen)(str)`.

Comment: @dfeuer; I never said pointer to a function is *pointer to pointer*.

Comment: OK, so how can `(******strlen)(str)` work exactly? I see that it *does*, but I don't understand it.

Comment: @dfeuer; [Why do all these crazy function pointer definitions all work? What is really going on?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6893288/2455888).

Comment: Thanks. It seems C is just completely crazy in that particular corner.