# Correct way to pass function pointer and the difference between them

Tags: c, callback, function-pointers

Reading about function pointers, came a question, and I found some answers here at stackoverflow, but I still do not understand.

So, what is the difference between these codes ?
What the compiler sees ?
Is there a correct way or a good programming practice to do this ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int a, int b);
void handle(int a, int b, int (*func)(int, int));

int main()
{
    handle(1, 2, sum); /*Here the third argument can be sum or &sum*/

    return 0;
}

void handle(int a, int b, int (*func)(int, int))
{
    printf("\nResult: %d.\n\n", func(a, b)); /*Here the second argument can be func(a, b) or (*func)(a, b)*/
}

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I can call handle in two ways:

```
handle(1, 2, sum);
handle(1, 2, &sum);
```

And into handle, I can call printf in two ways:

```
printf("\nResult: %d.\n\n", func(a, b)); 
printf("\nResult: %d.\n\n", (*func)(a, b));
```

All these ways can be combined, so we have 4 different combined ways.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you add those answers that you've looked at so far?

Comment: [One question that I've looked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi)

Comment: The duplicate is a C++ question, however in this respect the two languages are the same

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I'm not so sure that this is a real duplicate, because although both these questions overlap significantly, I don't think a good answer to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-all-these-crazy-function-pointer-definitions-all-work-what-is-really-goi) would necessarily answer the core question here, which as I see it is *"Is there a correct way or a good programming practice to do this ?"*

Comment: Also, as long as we're telling people not to ask "C/C++" questions because they're distinct languages, we shouldn't be pointing questions about C to answers about C++, even if they happen to be applicable in the given case.

Comment: @caf If both languages handle the situation in exactly the same way, I don't think it is necessary to have two parallel threads that will have identical questions and answers but with  a slightly different tag.

Comment: @caf your answer seems sufficient to answer the third of OP's questions

Answer (score 2):

Formally, both are just as correct as each other, and in practice you are likely to see either used.

Personally I would use:

```
handle(1, 2, sum);
```

and

```
printf("\nResult: %d.\n\n", func(a, b));
```

because I do not think the extraneous operators add any value.