# Assign static function to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, static

I was surprised to find the first two assignments seem to be equivalent - what's going on?

```
#include "stdio.h"

static int foo() {
  return 3;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  void* fp1 = foo;
  void* fp2 = &foo;

  printf("fp1 is %p\n", fp1);
  printf("fp2 is %p\n", fp2);
}
```

Sample output:

```
fp1 is 0x100fd2f70
fp2 is 0x100fd2f70
```

Why - when assigning to a `void*` is `foo` the same as `&foo?`

Comment: Here's another good one: [Why do function pointer definitions work with any number of ampersands '&' or asterisks '*'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6893285/643383)

Comment: What would two different results represent?