# Fetching a method pointer from the vtable in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

For an exercise I need to call a virtual method by way of the virtual method table (vtable). I'm experiencing some behavior I can't understand--the correct method is called, but with the wrong value for `this`. Here's some code that first demonstrates the correct behavior by fetching the method pointer directly, then demonstrates the wonky behavior by using the vtable:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Thing
{
public:
  virtual void foo()
  {
    std::printf("this:\t\t%p (in foo())\n", this);
  }
};

typedef void (Thing::*METHOD_PTR)();

void print_method_ptr(METHOD_PTR ptr) {
  // Helper function to display method pointers.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof ptr; ++i)
    printf("%d ", reinterpret_cast<char *>(&ptr)[i]);
}

void direct(Thing* thing_ptr) {
  std::printf("In direct().\n");

  // Get the pointer directly.
  METHOD_PTR foo_ptr = &Thing::foo;

  std::printf("&Thing::foo: ");
  print_method_ptr(&Thing::foo);
  std::printf("\nfoo_ptr: ");
  print_method_ptr(foo_ptr);
  if (foo_ptr == &Thing::foo) {
    std::printf("\nfoo_ptr == &Thing::foo\n");
  } else {
    std::printf("\nfoo_ptr != &Thing::foo\n");
  }

  std::printf("thing_ptr:\t%p\n", thing_ptr);
  (thing_ptr->*foo_ptr)();
}

void via_vtable(Thing* thing_ptr) {
  std::printf("In via_vtable().\n");

  // Retrieve foo_ptr from the vtable.
  METHOD_PTR** thing_ptr_cast = reinterpret_cast <METHOD_PTR**> (thing_ptr);
  METHOD_PTR* vtable_ptr = *thing_ptr_cast;
  METHOD_PTR foo_ptr = vtable_ptr[0];

  std::printf("&Thing::foo: ");
  print_method_ptr(&Thing::foo);
  std::printf("\nfoo_ptr: ");
  print_method_ptr(foo_ptr);
  if (foo_ptr == &Thing::foo) {
    std::printf("\nfoo_ptr == &Thing::foo\n");
  } else {
    std::printf("\nfoo_ptr != &Thing::foo\n");
  }

  std::printf("thing_ptr:\t%p\n", thing_ptr);
  (thing_ptr->*foo_ptr)();
}

int main()
{
  Thing thing;

  direct(&thing);
  std::printf("\n");
  via_vtable(&thing);

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
In direct().
&Thing::foo: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
foo_ptr: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
foo_ptr == &Thing::foo
thing_ptr:  0x7fffc6054940
this:       0x7fffc6054940 (in foo())

In via_vtable().
&Thing::foo: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
foo_ptr: -42 9 64 0 0 0 0 0 53 84 104 105 110 103 0 0 
foo_ptr != &Thing::foo
thing_ptr:  0x7fffc6054940
this:       0xe76e2f6d9d75 (in foo())
```

This is very confusing. My main questions:

- In `via_vtable()`, why does `foo_ptr != &Thing::foo`?
- Why does `foo()` still get called even though the method pointer is apparently incorrect?
- When `foo()` is called via the vtable, why is the value for `this` incorrect?
- Is there a better way to retrieve the method from the vtable?

For the exercise I've been directed to the [Wikipedia page for Virtual method tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), which explains their memory layout for g++.

I'm using g++ 4.8.4 on 64-bit Linux.

EDIT: Using `-fdump-class-hierarchy` with g++ suggests that the Wikipedia page is wrong about the vtable memory layout:

```
Vtable for Thing
Thing::_ZTV5Thing: 3u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI5Thing)
16    (int (*)(...))Thing::foo
```

However, that doesn't explain how `foo()` was actually executed before (and it certainly doesn't explain the wrong `this` in `foo()`.) Also, if I change `METHOD_PTR foo_ptr = vtable_ptr[0];` to `METHOD_PTR foo_ptr = vtable_ptr[1];` (which should then be offset 16, since `sizeof(METHOD_PTR)` is 16), I get a segmentation fault when I call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to call the virtual method. Note that I've changed the `typedef` and the line that actually calls the method.

```
#include <cstdio>

class Thing
{
public:
  virtual void foo()
  {
    std::printf("this:\t\t%p (in foo())\n", this);
  }
};

typedef void (*METHOD_PTR)(Thing*);

void via_vtable(Thing* thing_ptr) {
  // Retrieve foo_ptr from the vtable.
  METHOD_PTR** thing_ptr_cast = reinterpret_cast <METHOD_PTR**> (thing_ptr);
  METHOD_PTR* vtable_ptr = *thing_ptr_cast;
  METHOD_PTR foo_ptr = vtable_ptr[0];

  std::printf("thing_ptr:\t%p\n", thing_ptr);
  (*foo_ptr)(thing_ptr);
}

int main()
{
  Thing thing;
  via_vtable(&thing);
  return 0;
}
```

This gives me the following output:

```
thing_ptr:  0x7fff5f739da0
this:       0x7fff5f739da0 (in foo())
```

I still don't understand why the entry in the vtable is a different type (and value) from `&Thing::foo`, nor why the vtable given by `-fdump-class-hierarchy` has different offsets than the runtime vtable. If the vtable provided a bound method (like a Python bound method, with `self` already determined), then it would make sense, but seeing as I still have to pass in a pointer to a `Thing` instance.... hrrm.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help.
[Why do function pointer definitions work with any number of ampersands '&' or asterisks '*'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-function-pointer-definitions-work-with-any-number-of-ampersands-or-as)

I have visual studio and in my case is `this` always same.
`sizeof(METHOD_PTR)` should be 4. It is only pointer.

Comment: Interesting! On my end sizeof(METHOD_PTR) is 16.