# How does a void typedef work in C

Tags: c, typedef

I am working with an intentionally obfuscated code that contains a weird typedef that I am not able to comprehend. Could anyone explain what the following typedef means:

```
typedef void (*p_t)(char* a1, char* a2, int a3);
```

Later in the main its being used as follows:

```
int main(void) {
    p_t p = &some_function;
    p("foo", "bar", 42);
}
```

Comment: What is this `int main(int argc, char** a2, char** a3)`?

Comment: Don't ever write this `p[strchr(P, a2[1][1])-P](a2[2], (argc>3?a2[3]:NULL), f((argc>2?a2[2]:NULL), (a3?a3[0]:NULL), (a2[1][strlen(a2[1])-1] != 055)));` kind of code. It's simply impossible to understand it. And there is no good reason to write it, except for those useless code obfuscation challenges and similar ideas.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi It's a traditional Unix `main` signature (`argc`, `argv`, `envp`).

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi This is an obfuscated code. It was meant to be like that.

Comment: Oh my god, there's a variable `p` and a variable `P`

Comment: Y'all act like you've never seen http://ioccc.org/years.html.

Comment: btw, that third argument `envp` in the `main()` is for environment variables

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4295432/7076153

Answer (score 9):

`typedef void (*p_t)(char* a1, char* a2, int a3);` is a `typedef` of a pointer to a function that accepts arguments `char* a1, char* a2, int a3` and returns a `void` (no return).

---

Think of a function declaration (without any `typedef` involved), for example:

```
void fn(char* a1, char* a2, int a3);
```

Now, suppose that you want some pointer `p` to point to this function, then an assignment like `p = fn` should make sense.  But what would the type of that `p` be?  It would be a pointer to a function, but since functions have different signatures (making the "type" of the function different), you need to also specify the signature of the function that it points to.  In your case, you need a pointer to a function that accepts three arguments: 1.) a pointer to a `char`, 2.) another pointer to a `char`, and 3.) an `int`.  Also, the function returns a `void`.  All this needs to be specified in the type of `p`.  So your `p` might be declared (and subsequently assigned) as

```
void (*p)(char* a1, char* a2, int a3);
p = fn;
```

The part that may look weird is the `*` (declaring `p` as a pointer to something), which needs to go in parentheses with the `p` identifier.  Seeing some construct like `(*p)(...)` should be a quick hint to ask yourself if you're looking at a pointer to a function.  If you're going to use such a pointer to a function over and over, rather than have to type all that out again and again (and risk inconsistencies should you decide to change the function signature), it is convenient to make a `typedef`.  In your case, this is

```
typedef void (*p_t)(char* a1, char* a2, int a3);
```

See the ["Clockwise/Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

---

In your example, you have

```
p_t p = &some_function;
```

This is declaring a variable `p` of type `p_t`.  As mentioned above, this is a pointer to a function that accepts three arguments and returns a `void`.  This line also initializes `p` with the value `&some_function`.  Apparently `some_function` is the identifier of a function that is defined somewhere and accepts these three arguments and returns a `void`.  It initializes `p` to point to this function, so that on the next line calls it:

```
p("foo", "bar", 42);
```

I'm surprised this isn't written as

```
(*p)("foo", "bar", 42);
```

This dereferences `p`, which gives the function `some_function`, then calls that function with the arguments `"foo"`, `"bar"`, and `42`.  This is convenient because you could (if you wanted) make `p` point to some other function (with the same signature).  The associated function can therefore be dynamic.

---

It is worth mentioning that the `&` in `p_t p = &some_function;` is not necessary.  It doesn't hurt anything, but it's not needed.  Another strange thing about pointers to functions is that you can reference and dereference as many times as you want, and they mean the same thing! (See
[Why do function pointer definitions work with any number of ampersands '&' or asterisks '*'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-function-pointer-definitions-work-with-any-number-of-ampersands-or-as))

Comment: @Roushan More what?

Comment: when used so? bit example if u dont bother

Comment: @Roushan ... What? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: ink added thanks @e0k

Comment: There is a command line tool that explains the type of some C declaration you give it. I forgot what it's called because I haven't used it in a while. Does anyone remember it? It would be a useful reference.

Comment: @e0k  not sure what is possible return type of some_function can u demo the scenario

Comment: @Roushan The return type has to match the signature given in the `typedef`.  Try to compile `typedef void (*p_t)();int main(){p_t p=main;}` and it will complain about the pointer type because `main()` returns an `int` not a `void`.

Comment: @e0k got it thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a `typedef` for a function pointer.

```
typedef void (*p_t)(char* a1, char* a2, int a3);
        ^      ^    ^
        |      |    |
      return   |    +-----+
      type     |          |
            typedef    argument list
             name
```

In this case, it's a `typedef` named `p_t`.  The function `return`s `void` and it's arguments are `char *, char *, int`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you use a tool to create this ASCII picture?  If so, which one?  Thanks!

Comment: @jszakmeister - No tool, just hit space to line things up.

Comment: That's what I figured, but thanks anyways! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in "The C Programming Language" by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.

For example `int *i` is a pointer to `int` because it says that expression `*i` should evaluate to type `int`. More examples of this:

- `int (*func)()` is a pointer to function returning `int` because expression `(*func)()` evaluates to type `int`.
- `int *p[8]` is an array of pointers to `int` because expression `*p[x]` evaluates to type `int`.
- `int (*p)[8]` is a pointer to array of 8 `int`'s (`int[8]`) because expression `(*p)[x]` evaluates to type `int`.
- `int (*(*p[8])())()` is an array of 8 pointers to functions returning pointers to a function returning `int` because expression `(*(*p[x])())()` evaluates to type `int`.

Therefor lets look at `typedef void (*p_t)(char* a1, char* a2, int a3)`:

- `(*p_t)` expression of type `p_t` might be dereferenced and called (pointer to function).
- It should be passed arguments of types `char *`, `char *` and `int`.
- The resulting type of that expression is `void`.

It is a pointer to function taking `char *`, `char *`, `int` which has no return value.