# Why do we use ampersand on a function name?

Tags: c

Why do we use an ampersand on a function name: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L991? The symbol `system_call` is a function so the content of the variable is already a memory address. Why taking it's address with ampersand? For example, I wrote this test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int receiver(void *);

int test() {
}

int main() {
        printf("%p %p\n", test, &test);
        receiver(test);
        receiver(&test);
}

int receiver(void *p) {
        printf("receiver %p\n", p);
}
```

The output is:

```
0x556baeada6b0 0x556baeada6b0
receiver 0x556baeada6b0
receiver 0x556baeada6b0
```

Using ampersand doesn't seem to do anything.

Further more, if I use

```
objdump -d .text test
```

Here is the result:

```
00000000000006b7 <main>:
 6b7:   55                      push   %rbp
 6b8:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6bb:   48 8d 15 ee ff ff ff    lea    -0x12(%rip),%rdx        # 6b0 <test>
 6c2:   48 8d 35 e7 ff ff ff    lea    -0x19(%rip),%rsi        # 6b0 <test>
 6c9:   48 8d 3d d4 00 00 00    lea    0xd4(%rip),%rdi        # 7a4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 6d0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 6d5:   e8 86 fe ff ff          callq  560 <printf@plt>
 6da:   48 8d 3d cf ff ff ff    lea    -0x31(%rip),%rdi        # 6b0 <test>
 6e1:   e8 13 00 00 00          callq  6f9 <receiver>
 6e6:   48 8d 3d c3 ff ff ff    lea    -0x3d(%rip),%rdi        # 6b0 <test>
 6ed:   e8 07 00 00 00          callq  6f9 <receiver>
 6f2:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 6f7:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 6f8:   c3                      retq
```

As you can see on both `6bb` and `6c2` the address of `test` is moved to a register with the same lea instruction. Besides, on `6da` and `6e6` the same lea instruction are used. Using the ampersand or not doesn't seem to make any difference even on the machine code level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do function pointer definitions work with any number of ampersands '&' or asterisks '\*'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-function-pointer-definitions-work-with-any-number-of-ampersands-or-as) (While it doesn't technically answer _why_ the author of the code you linked to chose to use an `&` instead of omitting it, that question may not be answerable except by finding the author and asking them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used in an expression (other than as the operand of `&`), any expression of function type (such as `test` in your example) is automatically converted to the address of the function.

This is dictated in section 6.3.2.1p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A function  designator is  an  expression  that  has  function  type. 
>   Except  when  it  is  the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the
>   `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning type" is converted to an expression
>   that has type "pointer to function returning type".

So `&test` and `test` evaluate to the same thing, as does `*test`, `**test`, `***test`, etc.

Comment: Then for this case https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L991, it is just a personal preference to use ampersand on a function name?

Comment: @darklord Basically, yes.  The ampersand can be used but is not required.