# C Function Pointer Differences

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have the following C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int x, int y, int (*compare)(int, int))
{
  return (*compare)(x,y) ? x : y;
}

int greater_than(int x, int y)
{
  if(x > y) return 1;
  else return 0;
}

int main(void) {
 printf("%d",max(6,7,greater_than));
}
```

It's just there to test function pointers. But the code still works the same even if i dont use `int (*compare)(int,int)` but `int compare(int,int)`. It also works if I don't dereference the function pointer or if use `int compare(int,int)` but still dereference. It also doesn't make a difference if I pass `greater_than` or `&greater_than`. Why is this?

With regards
Nova

Comment: It takes a function pointer, but if you pass the function's name instead, it will automatically decay to a pointer of that function. Similarly to how arrays decay to pointers, too.

Comment: A function provided as argument (not as a function call), the compiler automatically takes its address - there is no other sensibe interpretation of `&` on a funcion.

Comment: Are you asking why `int max(int x, int y, int compare(int, int))` works and behaves the same as the posted code?

Answer (score 4):

These 2 versions are equivalent:

- `int max(int x, int y, int (*compare)(int, int))`
- `int max(int x, int y, int compare(int, int))`

Just like arrays passed as parameters to functions "decay" into pointers to the first element, similar "decay" happens to functions. They decay into function pointers. The standard says

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to
>   function returning type’’

So the second (obscure) version above gets silently translated by the compiler into the first version. But there is never a reason to declare a function inside a parameter list, so this whole issue is quite exotic.

---

As for why `compare(x,y)` works as fine as `(*compare)(x,y)` or for that matter `(*****compare)(x,y)`, it is because whenever you use either a function name or function pointer, you always get a function pointer. If you try to de-reference the function pointer, you get the function. Which again bounces back implicitly into a function pointer.

See [Why do function pointer definitions work with any number of ampersands '&' or asterisks '*'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-function-pointer-definitions-work-with-any-number-of-ampersands-or-as)

---

Beginners and veterans all alike can safely forget about the above obscure rules, and just do this:

```
int max(int x, int y, int (*compare)(int, int))
{
  return compare(x,y) ? x : y;
}
```

Or better yet, use typedef:

```
typedef int compare_t (int, int);

...

int max(int x, int y, compare_t* compare)
{
  return compare(x,y) ? x : y;
}
```

Comment: I do like the second "obscure" parameter declaration... :( less to type.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer given by Lundin before.
Rep too low to comment, so I'll put this here as extra. I saw the link on a similar post here on stackoverflow, I liked the tutorial.

Origin of link to tutorial is this question: [How do you pass a function as a parameter in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c)

Function pointer tutorial mentioned in the above: http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

Hope I'm not being presumptuous, I liked it, maybe it will make for a pleasant read for you as well.