# Asking the syntax of Function pointer. - int (int)

Tags: c, c99

I've learned function pointer is used as :

```
double (*ptr)(double)

ptr = my_func1;
```

And also, using 'typedef' could be

```
typedef double (*func1)(double);

func1 my_func1;
```

But I can't understand why this code is valid below :

```
int main(void){
    test(a);
}

void test(int f(int))
{\
    int x;\
    (f==a)?(x=1):(x=2);\
    printf("%d",f(x));\
}
```

What's that `int f(int)`? Is it same syntax with function pointer?

I know the type `int (*)int` is valid, but I've never seen the type `int (int).`

And Also I can't understand why the syntax in the main fuction `"int f(int) = func_1"` is invalid but in the 'test' function's parameter `int f(int) = a is valid.`

Please tell me TT Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's valid? What is `a`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a function or pass a function pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987314/pass-a-function-or-pass-a-function-pointer-in-c)

Comment: Sorry for confusing. a is a kind of another fuction which is declared as : int a(int){return z;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int f(int)` is a function declaration.

In C, two kinds of entities cannot be passed into functions, returned from functions or assigned: arrays and functions.

If parameters of these types are declared, they are silently turned into pointers.

A parameter `int f(int)` is changed to mean `int (*f)(int)`, similarly to the way a parameter `int a[3]` is changed to `int *a`.

You might see a gratuitous warning if you declare a function one way, but define it the other; e.g.:

```
void test(int (*)(int));

void test(int f(int))
{
}
```

I've seen some version of GCC warn about this, even though it is correct; the definition and declaration are 100% compatible.

Because inside `test`, `f` is declared as a pointer, it is assignable:

```
f = some_func
```

However, in a situation where `int f(int)` declares a function, the identifier is not assignable:

```
{
  int f(int);     // "There exists an external f function" -- okay.
  f = some_func;  // Error; what? You can't assign functions!

}
```

Outside of function parameter declarations, functions and pointers to functions are distinguished in the usual way, as are arrays and pointers.